# Android Wear not picking up localized version

Tags: localization, wear-os

I have a soccer/football referee timing app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pipperpublishing.soccerrefpro) with localizations for GB/AU/NZ. If I set my language/locale to English(Australia) on the phone, the app name correctly changes to "Football Referee Pro" and various other language differences.

However, on the watch (Sony Smartwatch SW3 running AW1.5), I still get the US-version of the app. I have tried re-installing on the watch, re-pairing (and picking English-UK on installation) but it stays the same.

On my Moto360 running AW2.0, I get the US-localization when I download from the Play Store.

I have re-read the localization developer information, but can't really find anything relevant. Any suggestions for next steps?

UPDATE: By using the Settings>Language and input option, I was able to more thoroughly test the 4 different language options (in my case en-US,-UK,-AU,-NZ). All 4 work correctlly on the phone, but only en-US and en-UK work on the watch. If I select -AU or -NZ, it defaults back to the en-US version on the watch.

I'm going to try String's suggestion below.

Comment: I actually ran into a problem like this just yesterday. Do you have a `resConfigs` directive in your Wear app's build.gradle, by any chance?

Comment: I don't think so but will check. I *do* have minifyenabled=true and wonder if the shrinking is somehow removing key resources. However when I examined the Wear apk it appears to have the compiled resource *with* the necessary translated strings.

Comment: I ask because I found that `resConfigs` was stripping out more translations than I'd meant it to. If that looks possible for you, I'll write up the details.

Comment: I would love to know more - it's about the only possibility I can think of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know that this is your issue, but here goes...

The [standard advice](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#unused-alt-resources) given for removing "unused" resources from your buld is to include a `resConfigs` property in your build.gradle, listing only those languages that you have localized your app to. Like so:

```
resConfigs "en", "fr"
```

However, this property restricts the resources to only the **defaults** for each language, and removes region-specific resources. For example, if you have an app that's mostly in English (`en`), but has a few country-specific strings (say `en-rUS` and `en-rGB`), these latter will be removed by the above `resConfigs` value - and users in both Britain and the USA will see the default strings.

AFAICT, the solution is to list **all** configurations that you want included in your APK. So in my example, we'd need:

```
resConfigs "en", "en-rUS", "en-rGB", "fr"
```

in order to have all country-specific configurations.

Note that there's been an issue opened for "wildcard" `resConfigs`, but it hasn't got much love: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69240488

Comment: Will definitely try this! Thanks!

Comment: I did insert the resConfigs line in the Wear build.gradle as:

     resConfigs "en", "en-rUS", "en-rAU", "en-rGB", "en-rNZ"

but it doesn't appear to have helped. However, I will keep pulling on this thread!